# How do I know which page was requested before login on a JSF 2 page

Tags: authentication, jsf-2, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I'm developing a web application with GlassFish 3.1 and JSF 2.0 / EJB 3.1. Some of my pages are secured. The secured URL-Parts are defined in the `web.xml` as URL-patterns. These pages are secured through a security-realm which redirects to a login page also defined in the `web.xml` as `login.xhtml`. On the `login.xhtml` my inputfields for username and password are connected to a session scoped backing bean which executes:

```
ExternalContext ec = getExternalContext();
HttpServletRequest request = getHttpServletRequest(ec);
request.login(username, password);
```

The EJB container is responsible for redirecting all incoming requests to secured areas with an invalid session to this page.

But, for example the user is bookmarking the page `index.xhtml` and was requesting this page. First he has to login over `login.xhtml`. He authenticates himself by typing his username+password and clicking the submit button.

The problem is: How to determine the target adress, in this case `index.html`?
The method `request.getRequestURI()` shows `login.xhtml` and not `index.html`. I can redirect always to `index.xhtml`, but what if the user has typed in `xyz.xhtml`? Is there any way?

Thanks

Adem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original request information are stored in the request object with the following keys:

> "javax.servlet.forward.request_uri"
>
> "javax.servlet.forward.query_string"

Comment: Thanks for answer. This put me to the right way to look for the solution!

Comment: Would it be possible to add some code to show how to read these keys? :)